# Acumatica get Sales Order by Customer Order field

Tags: acumatica

I am attempting to retrieve a single sales order based on the Customer Order field in Acumatica with the Contract Based API.  See my code below, which I based off of code in the [Contract Based Documentation](http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/I210-Contract-Based-Web-Services-6.0.pdf) (page 82).

```
public SalesOrder GetSalesOrder(string orderNumber)
{
    var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding()
    {
        AllowCookies = true,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 655360,
        MaxBufferSize = 655360,
        SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)
    };

    var soToBeFound = new SalesOrder()
    {
        OrderType = new StringValue { Value = "SO" },
        CustomerOrder = new StringValue { Value = orderNumber }
    };

    var address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AcumaticaUrl"]);


    using (DefaultSoapClient client = new DefaultSoapClient(binding, address))
    {
        client.Login(_acumaticaUid, _acumaticaPwd, _acumaticaCompany, null, null);

        var existingOrder = (SalesOrder)client.Get(soToBeFound);

        client.Logout();

        return existingOrder;
    }
}
```

When I execute this code I get this exception:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after
>   00:01:59.9880722. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to
>   Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout."

As you can see, I've already increased the timeout to 2 minutes, which seems like forever.  Is the Acumatica API really just this slow?  Or am I doing something wrong in code?

**EDIT:**

When I try to get by the "OrderNbr" field instead of "CustomerOrder" field, it works perfectly.  Is getting by "CustomerOrder" not allowed in this way?  If not, how can I use "CustomerOrder" in a get request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do search via the Contract-Based API, it's required to assign instance of the [FieldType]Search type instead of [FieldType]Value to all fields used in search criteria (`StringSearch` must be used instead of `StringValue` in your case):

```
var soToBeFound = new SalesOrder()
{
    OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = "SO" },
    CustomerOrder = new StringSearch { Value = orderNumber }
};
```

Just to confirm, `StringSearch` is also used in the sample on page 82 from the Contract Based documentation.

Comment: This is absolutely correct!  In the documentation, it shows that null will be returned if the item does not exist, however I am getting a `PX.Api.ContractBased.NoEntitySatisfiesTheConditionException`.  Can I configure it to return Null instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no option to configure the API to return Null instead of throwing an exception. It will keep throwing `NoEntitySatisfiesTheConditionException` if an item does not exist in the application.